# Find matrices $A,P\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|A\|_{op}\neq \|P^{-1}AP\|_{op}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm trying to answer:

Find matrices $A,P\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\|A\|_{op}\neq \|P^{-1}AP\|_{op}$. If however $PP^t=I$ then equality holds.

This, however, does not make sense to me, as if P is invertible so P does not suppose to change operatorial norms.

Where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition should be that if $PP^t = I$, then $P$ is an isometry (preserving lengths of all vectors). As you say in this case $\|A\|_{op} = \|P^{-1}AP\|_{op}$. So that must mean that in the more general case it must be that $P$ changes the lengths of vectors that causes $\|A\|_{op} \neq \|P^{-1}AP\|_{op}$. Note that if $$P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right) = 2\cdot I$$

then you would still have equality, so you need a $P$ that changes the lengths of vectors in different ways. Then it makes sense because $A$ would be a rotation that rotates one eigenspace onto another.

Putting this all together we see that

$$P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \text{and } 
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right) $$

work.